# Flutter keys don't work with multiple widgets (in this case)

Tags: flutter, dart, key

I'm facing a problem with a widget (ExTrainingItem) of my Flutter app. The parent widget (InTrainingWidget) is a card with some other stuff and a ListView.separated where the child widget is built. The parent (InTrainingScreen) of the parent widget (InTrainingWidget) is a screen with multiple InTrainingWidget children shown based on an index controlled by the user. Going back to the last child widget (ExTrainingItem), it has a container that, if it's clicked, changes colour. However, when the user switches the index, the box at the same index of all the next widgets is coloured. I don't know if it's related to keys (which I tried to use without success) or something like that. I'm new to Flutter and I'm still learning some advanced topics. Thanks for your time. Here are the widgets:

InTrainingScreen (grandad):

```
import 'package:final_gym/models/workout_model.dart';
import 'package:final_gym/widgets/Schede/in_training_widget.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';

class InTrainingScreen extends ConsumerStatefulWidget {
  const InTrainingScreen({
    super.key,
    required this.workout,
    required this.schedaIndex,
    required this.workoutIndex,
  });

  final Workout workout;
  final int schedaIndex;
  final int workoutIndex;

  @override
  ConsumerState<InTrainingScreen> createState() => _InTrainingScreenState();
}

class _InTrainingScreenState extends ConsumerState<InTrainingScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12),
              child: InTrainingWidget(
                workout: widget.workout,
                workoutIndex: widget.workoutIndex,
                schedaIndex: widget.schedaIndex,
              ),
            )),
    );
  }
}
```

InTrainingWidget (parent):

```
import 'package:final_gym/models/workout_model.dart';
import 'package:final_gym/providers/user_provider.dart';
import 'package:final_gym/widgets/Schede/body_exercise.dart';
import 'package:final_gym/widgets/Schede/ex_training_card.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';

class InTrainingWidget extends ConsumerStatefulWidget {
  const InTrainingWidget({
    super.key,
    required this.workout,
    required this.schedaIndex,
    required this.workoutIndex,
  });

  final Workout workout;
  final int schedaIndex;
  final int workoutIndex;

  @override
  ConsumerState<InTrainingWidget> createState() => _InTrainingWidgetState();
}

class _InTrainingWidgetState extends ConsumerState<InTrainingWidget> {
  int indexEx = 0;
  List<double> volExList = [];
  double volWorkout = 0;

  void updateVolume(double v) {
    volWorkout += v;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // final userP = ref.watch(userStateNotifier);
    // final userPnot = ref.watch(userStateNotifier.notifier);
    TextStyle style = Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyLarge!.copyWith(
        color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.onBackground.withOpacity(.5));

    return SafeArea(
      child: Container(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(30),
          child: Column(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
               ...
ListView.separated(
                          physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                          shrinkWrap: true,
                          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                            return ExTrainingItem(
                              exercise: widget.workout.exerciseList[index],
                              exerciseIndex: indexEx,
                              schedaIndex: widget.schedaIndex,
                              workoutIndex: widget.workoutIndex,
                              setIndex: index,
                              callBack: (v) {
                                updateVolume(v);
                                setState(() {
                                  volExList.add(v);
                                });
                              },
                            );
                          },
                          separatorBuilder: (context, index) => Container(
                            color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.secondary,
                            height: 4,
                          ),
                          itemCount: widget
                              .workout.exerciseList[indexEx].setList.length,
                        ),
              ...)),
    );
  }
}
```

ExTrainingItem (child):

```
import 'package:final_gym/models/personal_exercise.dart';
import 'package:final_gym/providers/set_type_provider.dart';
import 'package:final_gym/providers/user_provider.dart';
import 'package:final_gym/utils/to_string_utils.dart';
import 'package:final_gym/widgets/Schede/set_type_select.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';

import '../../models/set.dart';

// ignore: must_be_immutable
class ExTrainingItem extends ConsumerStatefulWidget {
  ExTrainingItem({
    super.key,
    required this.exercise,
    required this.schedaIndex,
    required this.workoutIndex,
    required this.exerciseIndex,
    required this.setIndex,
    required this.callBack,
  });

  PersonalExercise exercise;
  final int schedaIndex;
  final int workoutIndex;
  final int exerciseIndex;
  final int setIndex;
  final Function(double v) callBack;

  @override
  ConsumerState<ExTrainingItem> createState() => _ExTrainingCardState();
}

class _ExTrainingCardState extends ConsumerState<ExTrainingItem> {
  double volumeF = 0;
  bool isCompleted = false;

  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    TextStyle style = Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyLarge!.copyWith(
        color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.onBackground);
    final userP = ref.watch(userStateNotifier);
    final userPnot = ref.watch(userStateNotifier.notifier);
    final setPnot = ref.watch(setTypesProvider.notifier);

    SetW set = userP
        .listaSchede[widget.schedaIndex]
        .workoutList[widget.workoutIndex]
        .exerciseList[widget.exerciseIndex]
        .setList[widget.setIndex];

    final cat = set.setType.category;

    double controllerKgs = set.kgs;
    int controllerReps = set.numReps;

    void addV(double kgs, int reps) {
    volumeF = kgs * reps;
    //userP.listaSchede[widget.schedaIndex].workoutList[widget.workoutIndex].exerciseList[widget.exerciseIndex].volumeList.add(volumeF);
    widget.callBack(volumeF);
  }
    

    Widget textForm(dynamic text, int index) {
      return TextFormField(
        key: UniqueKey(),
        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
        autocorrect: false,
        keyboardType: index == 0
            ? const TextInputType.numberWithOptions(decimal: true)
            : TextInputType.number,
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          hintText: text.toString(),
          hintStyle: style,
          border: InputBorder.none,
        ),
        onChanged: (value) {
          if (double.tryParse(value) is double && index == 0) {
            text = ToStringUtils().doubleToString(double.parse(value));
            controllerKgs = double.parse(value);
          }
          if (int.tryParse(value) is int && index == 1) {
            text = int.parse(value).toString();
            controllerReps = int.parse(value);
          }
        },
      );
    }

    return Dismissible(
      onDismissed: (direction) => userPnot.deleteSet(widget.schedaIndex, widget.workoutIndex, widget.exerciseIndex, set),
      key: UniqueKey(),
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
        children: [
          SizedBox(
            child: InkWell(
              key: UniqueKey(),
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                  child: ClipRRect(
                    borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(5)),
                    child: Container(
                      height: 20,
                      width: 20,
                      color: isCompleted
                          ? Theme.of(context).colorScheme.secondary
                          : Colors.white12, //TODO: aggiungere animazione
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                onTap: () {
                  setState(() {
                    isCompleted = !isCompleted;
                    set.kgs = controllerKgs;
                    set.numReps = controllerReps;
                  });
                  if (isCompleted) {
                    addV(controllerKgs, controllerReps);
                  } else {
                    volumeF = 0;
                  }
                }),
          ),
          Expanded(
            key: GlobalKey(),
            child: InkWell(
              child: Text(
                set.setType.title,
                style: setPnot.getTextStyle(cat, context),
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              ),
              onTap: () {
                showModalBottomSheet(
                  context: context,
                  builder: (context) {
                    return SetTypeSelect(
                        schedaIndex: widget.schedaIndex,
                        workoutIndex: widget.workoutIndex,
                        exerciseIndex: widget.exerciseIndex,
                        setIndex: widget.setIndex,
                        voidCallback: () {
                          setState(() {
                            set = userP
                                .listaSchede[widget.schedaIndex]
                                .workoutList[widget.workoutIndex]
                                .exerciseList[widget.exerciseIndex]
                                .setList[widget.setIndex];
                          });
                        });
                  },
                );
              },
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: textForm(ToStringUtils().doubleToString(set.kgs), 0),
            //   child: Text(
            // ToStringUtils().doubleToString(set.kgs),
            // textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: textForm(set.numReps, 1),
          ),
          Expanded(
              child: Text(
            set.rpe.toString(),
            style: style,
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          ))
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I'm facing a problem with a widget (ExTrainingItem) of my Flutter app. The parent widget (InTrainingWidget) is a card with some other stuff and a ListView.separated where the child widget is built. The parent (InTrainingScreen) of the parent widget (InTrainingWidget) is a screen with multiple InTrainingWidget children shown based on an index controlled by the user. Going back to the last child widget (ExTrainingItem), it has a container that, if it's clicked, changes colour. However, when the user switches the index, the box at the same index of all the next widgets is coloured. I don't know if it's related to keys (which I tried to use without success) or something like that. I'm new to Flutter and I'm still learning some advanced topics. Thanks for your time. Here are the widgets:

InTrainingScreen (grandad):

```
import 'package:final_gym/models/workout_model.dart';
import 'package:final_gym/widgets/Schede/in_training_widget.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';

class InTrainingScreen extends ConsumerStatefulWidget {
  const InTrainingScreen({
    super.key,
    required this.workout,
    required this.schedaIndex,
    required this.workoutIndex,
  });

  final Workout workout;
  final int schedaIndex;
  final int workoutIndex;

  @override
  ConsumerState<InTrainingScreen> createState() => _InTrainingScreenState();
}

class _InTrainingScreenState extends ConsumerState<InTrainingScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12),
              child: InTrainingWidget(
                workout: widget.workout,
                workoutIndex: widget.workoutIndex,
                schedaIndex: widget.schedaIndex,
              ),
            )),
    );
  }
}
```

InTrainingWidget (parent):

```
import 'package:final_gym/models/workout_model.dart';
import 'package:final_gym/providers/user_provider.dart';
import 'package:final_gym/widgets/Schede/body_exercise.dart';
import 'package:final_gym/widgets/Schede/ex_training_card.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';

class InTrainingWidget extends ConsumerStatefulWidget {
  const InTrainingWidget({
    super.key,
    required this.workout,
    required this.schedaIndex,
    required this.workoutIndex,
  });

  final Workout workout;
  final int schedaIndex;
  final int workoutIndex;

  @override
  ConsumerState<InTrainingWidget> createState() => _InTrainingWidgetState();
}

class _InTrainingWidgetState extends ConsumerState<InTrainingWidget> {
  int indexEx = 0;
  List<double> volExList = [];
  double volWorkout = 0;

  void updateVolume(double v) {
    volWorkout += v;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // final userP = ref.watch(userStateNotifier);
    // final userPnot = ref.watch(userStateNotifier.notifier);
    TextStyle style = Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyLarge!.copyWith(
        color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.onBackground.withOpacity(.5));

    return SafeArea(
      child: Container(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(30),
          child: Column(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
               ...
ListView.separated(
                          physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                          shrinkWrap: true,
                          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                            return ExTrainingItem(
                              exercise: widget.workout.exerciseList[index],
                              exerciseIndex: indexEx,
                              schedaIndex: widget.schedaIndex,
                              workoutIndex: widget.workoutIndex,
                              setIndex: index,
                              callBack: (v) {
                                updateVolume(v);
                                setState(() {
                                  volExList.add(v);
                                });
                              },
                            );
                          },
                          separatorBuilder: (context, index) => Container(
                            color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.secondary,
                            height: 4,
                          ),
                          itemCount: widget
                              .workout.exerciseList[indexEx].setList.length,
                        ),
              ...)),
    );
  }
}
```

ExTrainingItem (child):

```
import 'package:final_gym/models/personal_exercise.dart';
import 'package:final_gym/providers/set_type_provider.dart';
import 'package:final_gym/providers/user_provider.dart';
import 'package:final_gym/utils/to_string_utils.dart';
import 'package:final_gym/widgets/Schede/set_type_select.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';

import '../../models/set.dart';

// ignore: must_be_immutable
class ExTrainingItem extends ConsumerStatefulWidget {
  ExTrainingItem({
    super.key,
    required this.exercise,
    required this.schedaIndex,
    required this.workoutIndex,
    required this.exerciseIndex,
    required this.setIndex,
    required this.callBack,
  });

  PersonalExercise exercise;
  final int schedaIndex;
  final int workoutIndex;
  final int exerciseIndex;
  final int setIndex;
  final Function(double v) callBack;

  @override
  ConsumerState<ExTrainingItem> createState() => _ExTrainingCardState();
}

class _ExTrainingCardState extends ConsumerState<ExTrainingItem> {
  double volumeF = 0;
  bool isCompleted = false;

  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    TextStyle style = Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyLarge!.copyWith(
        color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.onBackground);
    final userP = ref.watch(userStateNotifier);
    final userPnot = ref.watch(userStateNotifier.notifier);
    final setPnot = ref.watch(setTypesProvider.notifier);

    SetW set = userP
        .listaSchede[widget.schedaIndex]
        .workoutList[widget.workoutIndex]
        .exerciseList[widget.exerciseIndex]
        .setList[widget.setIndex];

    final cat = set.setType.category;

    double controllerKgs = set.kgs;
    int controllerReps = set.numReps;

    void addV(double kgs, int reps) {
    volumeF = kgs * reps;
    //userP.listaSchede[widget.schedaIndex].workoutList[widget.workoutIndex].exerciseList[widget.exerciseIndex].volumeList.add(volumeF);
    widget.callBack(volumeF);
  }
    

    Widget textForm(dynamic text, int index) {
      return TextFormField(
        key: UniqueKey(),
        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
        autocorrect: false,
        keyboardType: index == 0
            ? const TextInputType.numberWithOptions(decimal: true)
            : TextInputType.number,
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          hintText: text.toString(),
          hintStyle: style,
          border: InputBorder.none,
        ),
        onChanged: (value) {
          if (double.tryParse(value) is double && index == 0) {
            text = ToStringUtils().doubleToString(double.parse(value));
            controllerKgs = double.parse(value);
          }
          if (int.tryParse(value) is int && index == 1) {
            text = int.parse(value).toString();
            controllerReps = int.parse(value);
          }
        },
      );
    }

    return Dismissible(
      onDismissed: (direction) => userPnot.deleteSet(widget.schedaIndex, widget.workoutIndex, widget.exerciseIndex, set),
      key: UniqueKey(),
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
        children: [
          SizedBox(
            child: InkWell(
              key: UniqueKey(),
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                  child: ClipRRect(
                    borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(5)),
                    child: Container(
                      height: 20,
                      width: 20,
                      color: isCompleted
                          ? Theme.of(context).colorScheme.secondary
                          : Colors.white12, //TODO: aggiungere animazione
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                onTap: () {
                  setState(() {
                    isCompleted = !isCompleted;
                    set.kgs = controllerKgs;
                    set.numReps = controllerReps;
                  });
                  if (isCompleted) {
                    addV(controllerKgs, controllerReps);
                  } else {
                    volumeF = 0;
                  }
                }),
          ),
          Expanded(
            key: GlobalKey(),
            child: InkWell(
              child: Text(
                set.setType.title,
                style: setPnot.getTextStyle(cat, context),
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              ),
              onTap: () {
                showModalBottomSheet(
                  context: context,
                  builder: (context) {
                    return SetTypeSelect(
                        schedaIndex: widget.schedaIndex,
                        workoutIndex: widget.workoutIndex,
                        exerciseIndex: widget.exerciseIndex,
                        setIndex: widget.setIndex,
                        voidCallback: () {
                          setState(() {
                            set = userP
                                .listaSchede[widget.schedaIndex]
                                .workoutList[widget.workoutIndex]
                                .exerciseList[widget.exerciseIndex]
                                .setList[widget.setIndex];
                          });
                        });
                  },
                );
              },
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: textForm(ToStringUtils().doubleToString(set.kgs), 0),
            //   child: Text(
            // ToStringUtils().doubleToString(set.kgs),
            // textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: textForm(set.numReps, 1),
          ),
          Expanded(
              child: Text(
            set.rpe.toString(),
            style: style,
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          ))
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I'd suggest making a copy of your project and gradually delete everything that is not related to the specific problem you are experiencing.  Then you'd have a simpler example that demonstrates the problem which would be easier for others to help you with.